# Specify xacro properties in launch file

Tags: ros, gazebo, roslaunch, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to specify the values for `<xacro:property>` tags in launch file ? I want to use a single `*.urdf.xacro` file using different values for the same property. Is it possible ?

For eg.:
In door.urdf.xacro

```
<xacro:property name = room value = "workroom" />
<link name = "${room}_door">
....
```

I would like to specify the value "workroom" for the property room in the launch file so that I can use the same `*.urdf.xacro` file for all the rooms in my gazebo world (kitchen, bedroom etc..). I know I can use TinyXML but it will be easier and simpler if I can specify the properties in launch file. Or is there any other way out ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59447/specify-xacro-properties-in-launch-file/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to use a [macro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro).
You may use something like this:

```
<xacro:macro name="whatever" params="room">
<link name = "${room}_door">
 ...
</link>
</xacro:macro>
<xacro:whatever room="workroom"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) with karma: 90 on 2013-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0